# Posso subir pastas junto com o código no GitHub?

Tags: github

Eu já coloquei códigos nos meus repositórios no Github uma vez, porém agora estou mexendo com site pelo Netbeans utilizando HTML5, e tenho outras pastas como do CSS, Javascript e afins. Tem possibilidade de, ao subir o código, subir essas pastas também?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O Git não permite ter diretórios vazios. Mas quando preciso subir uma pasta crio um arquivo oculto dentro do diretório para fazer upload desse diretório. Por exemplo:

```
touch pasta/.teste
```

Aplique o `git add pasta/` para adicionar uma pasta específica ou `git add .` para subir todas as pastas e as alterações.

Comment: Bem lembrado, jow +1

Comment: Eu nunca tinha pensado nisso, +1.

Comment: o CakePHP usa um arquivo `.empty`

Comment: E uma grande parcela da comunidade utiliza o arquivo `.gitkeep`.

Answer (score 13):

Pode, desde que estas pastas não estejam listadas no arquivo .gitignore e não estejam vazias elas serão enviadas para o repositório.

Não esqueça de adicionar as pastas antes de *commitar*

```bash
git add pasta/.gitkeep
```

Se quiser enviar uma pasta que não tenha arquivos no *commit*, vai ser necessário usar algum método alternativo pra isso.

Uma abordagem que eu uso bastante é criar um arquivo vazio com o nome `.gitkeep`. Dessa forma, consigo saber qual a utilidade do arquivo só olhando para o seu nome.

Você pode criar este arquivo usando o comando `touch`

```bash
touch pasta/.gitkeep
```

Comment: E se não estiverem vazias. Pastas vazias são desconsideradas pelo `git` (por padrão, creio eu).

Comment: Para pastas vazias é só add uma index.html com nada dentro, assim que faço pelo menos

Answer (score 3):

Eu gosto de fazer de um jeito que aprendi a fazer nos projetos no Laravel. Quando preciso ter a pasta em produção, mas não preciso que os arquivos dentro dessas pastas sejam monitorados, eu crio um  `.gitignore` dentro da pasta em questão e coloco o seguinte trecho:

E coloco `PastaQueEuQuero/.gitignore`:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Nesse caso apenas o arquivo `.gitgnore` junto com a pasta é mandado para o repositório ao fazer `git add PastaQueEuQuero`.

Answer (score -3):

Eu aprendi a criar as pastas assim:[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVsJ9.jpg)
Dentro do Repositório seleciono:
Add File/ Create new file
após aparecer o endereço
Repositorio/ digite aqui o nome da pasta a ser criada + "/"
complete com um arquivo .txt e no botão a direita verde - Commit Changes preencha todos os campos até salvar